# VBA copy value from column C in loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to modify the line of code with the comment MODIFY below. Currently this line of code is copying the cell in the column that it is checking. What I need it to do is copy a different cell from the same row. I need it to copy the cell from row C. Thank you

```
For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
For Each c In rng
    If ws1.Range("Q" & i).Value = c.Value Then
       ws1.Cells(i, lnCols).Value = "KEEP"
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
       'Range("H" & c.Row).Value = c.Value ' MODIFY
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

There's better ways of doing this but with what you've put up here you go, this should do what you want.

```
For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
    For Each c In rng
        If ws1.Range("Q" & i).Value = c.Value Then
           ws1.Cells(i, lnCols).Value = "KEEP"
           Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & c.Row).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(c.Row, 3).Value ' MODIFY
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Next i
```

Comment: This code gives the error of "sub or function not defined" for some reason

Comment: Sorry just seen the typo

Comment: Have just fixed the line. Please try it again - is what happens when you free type outside of a proper editor

Comment: Okay, so this runs but maybe I wasn't clear. This code copies the cell from column C of sheet 2 into column H of sheet 2. I'm looking to copy the cell of column C sheet 1 into column H sheet 2. Is that possible? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's perfectly possible but not what your code was doing. I feel like you  haven't written this yourself. SO is not a code writing service. Declare your  ranges properly in future.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

```
For i = lnLastRow1 To lnTopRow1 Step -1
    For Each c In Rng
        If ws1.Range("Q" & i).Value = c.Value Then
            ws1.Cells(i, lnCols).Value = "KEEP"
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & c.Row).Value = Range("C" & c.Row).Value ' MODIFY
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Next i
```